# What is the point of "cd ." command in Linux?

Tags: linux

I just began to learn to use Linux but I am just curious what would be the purpose of this command as it really doesn't do anything from what I have learned.

Comment: Same point as concatenating two empty strings.

Comment: Should someone writing a command go out of their way to find all uses of it they consider pointless and make sure those uses cause errors? If not, why wouldn't you expect this to work, despite not having obvious uses?

Comment: You can just not use that command - just because you can write a command doesn't mean it's gonna be useful. Imagine moving a file where the source and the destination are the exact same place! Doesn't make sense, but you can totally still do it. Same case here.

Comment: Sometimes the side effect of the shell action does matter. Consider `mount /dev/something .` . `ls` will still show the old directory beneath this new mount point (most likely empty). `cd .` should do nothing, but actually the shell will translate it to an absolute path and actually change the directory to the new mountpoint. `ls` will now show the contents. I use this often after `mount [...] .`

Comment: To the folks voting to reopen -- wouldn't this make more sense to migrate to [unix.se]? It has a good answer, but that doesn't make it a quality on-topic question.

Answer (score 4):

The point of the `cd .` command is to not create special cases merely because they are pointless.

The `cd` command is useful. Having a relative path that always means "the current directory" is useful. This means that the `cd .` command is possible.

At this point there are two options. Either create a special case disallowing it, or accept that freedom to `cd` anywhere also means the freedom to `cd` to where you already are, and accept it as harmless.

Unix, wisely, chose the later.